# What's the name for this skateboard trick? (180 kickturn)

Tags: terminology, skateboarding

So I'm wondering if there's a special name for this trick. It's very basic. You're moving forward, and you do a 180 degree kickturn (i.e. pivot off the tail, turn the nose 180 degrees). At the end you're still going forward. You just have the tail in front and the nose in the back. Is there a special name for this trick?

I'd think it would be called a 180 spin, but looking online a 180 spin usually refers to an ollie with 180 degree spin. This is simpler than that. I looked at reverts also, but in a revert the wheels slide instead of pivot.

This isn't an endover because for an endover you pivot on the nose.

Is this just called a 180 kickturn? I tried googling '180 kickturn', but I only see it used in the context of ramps. I'm just referring to a 180 spin on flatground.

Note that the body turns 180 along with the board.

Comment: If I understood correctly... I think you're describing a [Shove it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBAW51ilpLw)...?

Comment: Well, it's like a shove-it, but your body turns along with the board. In a shove-it, only the board turns.

Answer (score 1):

So you are saying there is NO POP involved right? And its on flatground? Thats really confusing.

If theres pop involved its either FS or BS 180. No Pop? I guess you could call it a revert but you dont really lift either side of your board on reverts so that wouldnt really be what you are describing

Comment: This guy calls it a manual revert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7A7H5O9yJmY&t=10s But he's doing legit long manuals before and after the turn. I'm thinking of only lifting the wheels during the turn.

Answer (score 1):

it is called "revert", no pivot on the wheel so it is not manual. U can search revert skateboard on youtube.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. The question appears to reject the suggestion of a revert, based on the movement of the wheels. Can you expand on your answer to explain why that idea was incorrect or inaccurate, and hence how *revert* is the correct term?

Answer (score 1):

If your back wheels are sliding, I'd consider this a *180° powerslide*, regardless of whether your front wheels are touching the ground or not.

Don't get hung up on what it's called though; just keep drawing outside the lines.